# only one central vertex

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $T$ be a tree and let $m$ be the legnth of the longest path in $T$. Prove that the center of $T$ consists of exactly one point if and only if $m$ is even.

So lets start by doing $\Rightarrow$ We can assume that the center of T consists of exaclty one point. So this points minimizes

$$
M(v) = \min_{w\in V} M(u)
$$
And length is the maximum path that can be undertaken from this point, lets call it point $v_u$. Now lets define $m$:
$$
m = \max_{u\in V}d(v_u,v)
$$

Now my intuition tells me  to prove the "$\Rightarrow$" by contradiction; lets assume that $m\neq$ even. But I cannot go on after this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be a vertex in the center, let $d$ be the maximal length of paths starting in $v$, let $k\ge1$ be the number neighbours $w$ of $v$ such that there is a path of length $d$ starting with $vw$.

If $k>1$, show that $m=2d$ and that no other vertex is in the center

If $k=1$ and $w$ is that unique neighbour, show that $w$ is also in the center and that at least one path $vu_1u_2\ldots u_{d-1}$ (with $u_1\ne w$ and $u_{d-1}$ a leaf) exists and thet $m=2d-1$.